# Issues with network interface bonding setup in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, debian, troubleshooting, bonding

Long time lurker but first time poster.

On my Debian server, I have set up interface bonding for two of the Ethernet interfaces to my managed Cisco switch. The bond type is 802.3ad and appears to be functioning correctly according to the switch configuration and LEDs.

The only error message I continue to receive on the console of the server at network bootup is "**bond1: invalid new link 3 on slave enp1s0f1**".

My configuration file @ "/etc/network/interfaces" reads as follows:

```
#The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#Ethernet interface #2
#auto enp1s0f1
#iface enp1s0f1 inet manual
#    bond-master bond1


#Ethernet interface #3
#auto enp1s0f0
#iface enp1s0f0 inet manual
#    bond-master bond1


# The bonded interface
auto bond1
iface bond1 inet static
    address 192.168.48.6
    netmask 255.255.255.128
    network 192.168.48.0
    broadcast 192.168.48.127
    gateway 192.168.48.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.48.1
    bond-mode 802.3ad
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-downdelay 300
    bond-updelay 300
    bond-slaves enp1s0f0 enp1s0f1
```

You may notice that lines 5-15 have been commented out. I tried the configuration file with these sections enabled, however it prevented the systemd "network.service" service from starting.

Additional Information:

1. Can't ping any other devices (including default gateway) from server with the exception of the loopback address.
2. Able to ping from switch to default gateway but not to server static ip.
3. Able to ping router to switch but not to the server static ip.
4. VLANs are being utilized on the switch in this configuration

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Turns out the configuration in the switch was missing something. The network interface card for the server is not VLAN "aware".

Hence, it was necessary to change the administrative PVID on the LAGG interface of the switch as it had been set to tag incoming frames from the server's network card to the switch with the wrong VLAN tag.